# PHP sessions and AJAX request (from injected JS code)

Tags: php, ajax, session

I think I forgetting something in my code but can't find what.

On my server I have simple `logging.php` file.
If I pass `user/password` parameters then a new session is created.
If I pass `loggout` the session is destroyed.
If I pass `report` the list of current session variables are reported on screen.

If I test the code writing urls in my browser all works fine. First invoke `.../logging.php?user=xxx&password=xxx`. The session is started and the session variables are reported to me. And finally I destroy the session passing the `logout` parameter.

If user request a `report` or a `logout` and no session exists a `HTTP-401` error code is returned to client.

On the other hand I have a piece of JavaScript code that I can inject on web page using a bookmarklet. Once code is injected I show a toolbar where user can write user/password and send to server.

The logging actions seems to works fine, and server returns me a 200 status code, but later if I make a request to `logout` the server returns me a 401 error, which mean no session exists.

I was using chrome and looking at HTTP request and responses can see that when I logging the server returns in the response different values for `PHPSESSIONID`.
That means two different `AJAX` request are considered different sessions. The server seems to not recognize the second request from `AJAX` as if it was started by the same client.

Repeat, the `PHP` code works fine if I execute using browser directly but not with AJAX request, so I think I forgetting something in AJAX.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

To be more concise, my problem is calling php from JavaScript. It seems there are no sessions started.

Imagine a very simple PHP code:

- logging.php: given a user/password starts a new session and also stores 'user' names as a session variable.
- request.php: which returns the user name stored as session variable.
- logout.php: which destroys the session.

My first AJAX request start a PHP session. That seems fine because a PHPSESSIONID cookie is returned from server. Also I store the user name as session variable.

The second AJAX request tries to get the user name (stored in the session) but it gets nothing and in addition a new PHPSESSIONID cookie is returned from server.

I know it seems impossible and more when I'm testing using browser url request and works fine, but it's the truth.

I'm forgetting something on AJAX, expiration times or something similar?

**Update again**

I made some tests and I found the problem but not the solution.

My JS code is injected through a bookmarklet. 
When I inject the code in a HTML page from my server, the AJAX requests works fine. The first (logging) request gets a PHPSESSID which is passed in subsequent request to the server.

On the other hand If I load google.com and inject the code, the first (logging) request gets the PHPSESSID too but later it is not sent with next requests.

Anyone has experienced the same issue? which is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

**Update again, again**

Ok finally I found my problem. Because my JS is injected from a different domain (current page is from domainA and my JS code comes from domainB) cookies are not cross domain, so PHPSESSID can be shared.

A possible soulution is when I logging I will return the PHP session ID in pice of JSON data and use it for subsequent calls.

Comment: Can you make your question conscise .. and clear

Comment: If you have updates or changes to your question, please include them by editing the original question. I've migrated your post below into your question here.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you're trying to log in a user by making an AJAX request to a URL, with the username and password provided in the URL? That's not really a safe construction, the password is very vulnerable this way?!

I would advice you to implement jQuery, and transer the login details using the $.POST command:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Make sure all your files (also those requested by AJAX) contain session_start(); on top of the file.
When every file contains session_start(); and you're using the same $_SESSION variables to check if a user is loggedin, it should work!

Comment: The user/password is no less vulnerable than if the AJAX call was being done by POST. If an attacker is somewhere in the middle, if they can sniff the url, they can sniff the body of the request. The major downside to login via get is that the u/p will be put into the sever's access_log

Answer (score 0):

Are both of your AJAX requests coming from the same page? The requests are Asynchronous, so it may be that the "logged in?" request is returning its result before the "log in" request goes through.

Comment: As I updated AJAX request comes from JS injected in the web page. For example I can load the google.com page, then inject JS code and make the requests. This way the request seems not hold the session ID.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have asked, I *hope* your code is (at its beginning more or less) something like:

A file logging.php like this:

```
<?php # file : loggging.php
if(!ini_set('session.auto_start')) 
// more stuff
if(!empty($_REQUEST['user']) && !empty($_REQUEST['passwd'])) {
    session_regenerate_sid(); // This is important (1)
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_REQUEST['user'];
    // Whatever
}
```

A file request.php like this..

```
<?php # file : request.php
if(!ini_set('session.auto_start')) 
// Whatever stuff to process data
var_dump($_SESSION);
  // Or a nice foreach($v as $i => $x) {
  //    echo("[$i] => $x\n<br />");
  // } instead :)
```

And your logout.php should read something like..

```
<?php # file : logout.php
if(!ini_set('session.auto_start')) session_start();
session_destroy();
```

You are probably not calling either `session_start()` or you are calling it twice.

To check this out try this: change all your `session_start()` lines for:

```
session_name('MYCoolNewName');
session_start();
```

Now your session should **not** read `PHPSESSID`, instead it should be `MYCoolNewName`.

If it is not, then your problem is the aforementioned.

(1) I put as important `session_regenerate_sid()` because opened authenticated sessions are a threat out there. I'll demonstrate it with an example.

Alice visits coolwebsite.com/login.php, which gives her a SID which I'll call `AliceSID`.
Alice tells Bob to visit coolwebsite.com/login.php?PHPSESSID=`AliceSID`, and when Bob does Alice could log in his account unless Bob's session was regenerated.